# Visual Studio Tools for Office (VSTO 2005) newbie deployment question

Tags: vsto, officedev

I have Visual Studio setup with a VSTO word project, and when I hit run it runs fine.

But, how do I setup a word document to use my code without having Visual Studio running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must deploy the [VSTO](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=F5539A90-DC41-4792-8EF8-F4DE62FF1E81&displaylang=en) runtime whether by hand or with an installer.  Check out this [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/johnrdurant/archive/2006/01/04/windows-installer.aspx) for a detailed explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using a Windows Installer project; starting point [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb332051.aspx).  You can also use the Publish Wizard.

A more general starting point can be found in MSDN [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hesc2788.aspx).